# How to stop restarting for loop when dependency change in useEffect (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to match pi value from input.
"pracInput" dependency has been used in useEffect so I can get latest value from input and check.
But the problem is that when I input some value the for loop restart.

if I input 9;
expected value=14159; counting: 5; progress width : 60 ;

if I input another value 2;
expected => value=141592; counting: 6; progress width : 72;

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const PiGame = () => {
  const [pracInput, setPracInput] = useState("1415");
  const pi = "141592653589793238462643";
  const [widthText, setWidthText] = useState(0);
  const [counting, setCounting] = useState(0);



  useEffect(() => {
    const runLoop2 = async () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < pracInput.length; i++) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        if (pracInput[i] === pi[i]) {
          console.log(i)
          console.log(true);
          setWidthText((prev) => prev + 12);
          setCounting((prev) => prev + 1);

        } else {
          console.log(false);
          alert('not match')

        }
  }
};
    runLoop2();
  }, [pracInput]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
const val = e.target.value;

if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(val)) {
  setPracInput(val);
}
 };


  return (
<div>
  <div>
    value: <input
      type="text"
      style={{
        width: "80%",
        marginTop: 100,
        height: 25,
        fontSize:25
      }}
      value={pracInput}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />



        <div style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>counting : {counting}</div>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "green", width: widthText, height: 20 }}></div>

        <div>progress width : {widthText}</div>


  </div>
</div>


);
};

export default PiGame;
```

Comment: Kindly explain what you actually want to implement? You wrote `useEffect` that will execute on change of `pracInput` but on the same time you don't want to restart `for loop`. Is this you want to implement?

Comment: Yes, You are right.

Comment: I update my code and description. please take a look and help me if possible.

Answer (score 0):

See your for loop is present inside the useEffect which gets triggered whenever your pracInput gets changed,so everything inside that useEffect will be triggered.Your pracInput is being changed when handleChange is being called ,so that means whenevr some input will be provided and `if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(val)) { setPracInput(val); }` becomes true,your pracInput will change and useEffect will be triggered and hence that for loop will start.And since your for loop requires your changes of pracInput ,moving it outside of the useEffect also wont make sense.
If you want to just start your for loop once only then remove it from that useEffect and do it like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
for loop goes here
},[]);
```

This will ensure that for loop runs just once ,that is when the component will render for the first time.

Edit: According to your output i think this should work:

```
const [widthText, setWidthText] = useState(0);
  const [counting, setCounting] = useState(0);


useEffect(() => {
const TimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      if(pracInput==="1415")
    {
    setCounting(4);
setWidthText(60);
}
    else
    {
    setCounting(pracInput.length+1);
    setWidthText(60+(pracInput.length-4)*12);
    }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(TimeoutId);
    

  }, [pracInput]);




const handleChange = (e) => {
const val = e.target.value;

if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(val)) {
  setPracInput(val);
}
 };
```

And you can now remove the for loop

Comment: Thanks Sakshi for your comment.
I know how it works.
 But how I can stop trigger again and again if I input some data.

Comment: well that's an answer ,not a comment :P .Does this solves your query?

Comment: No, 
Input will be changed , for loop would not trigger again if start once and it will complete input length.
please help

Comment: useEffect that will execute on change of pracInput but on the same time I don't want to restart for loop.

Comment: so means from where you want to start the for loop ?

Comment: User will input continuously but the for loop will check without restarting.

please see http://www.cow-pi.com/ site. please click "Go" or press g from right side and input 1592. you will see it is checking with green bg of text.

Comment: i am not completely getting your problem,you want the for loop to start on changing pracInput BUT just once ?is that what you mean? y

Comment: for now I have default value 1415 and for loop start automatically after 1sec.
I will input 92653 but the for loop would not restart and complete upto 121592653

Comment: I update my code and description. please take a look and help me if possible.

Comment: for your code , if I input 9 then I am getting value: 141514159, counting: 9, progress width: 21

you can run my update code and please wait 4s. you will get counting: 4, progress width: 48 now input 9, means value would be 14159 I want counting: 5 and progress width: 60 add another digit 2 means value would be 141592 I want counting: 6 and progress width: 72

Comment: yea there were few bugs,check the new code.

Comment: inside if it should be `if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(val)) {
  setPracInput(val);
}`

Comment: Wow, Sakshi your attempt is very good. it is working but I used for loop because of 1s delay for every checking. how we can delay

Comment: updated my ans.you can delay it more by increasing the value from 1000 to whatever you wish.

Comment: also need to check with pi value if true or false

Comment: why do you want to check that?how it should affect your output?

Comment: I am trying to convert http://www.cow-pi.com/ site to react.
its a pi game. user will input there memorizing pi value like 141592... and function will check is this correct or not for every single value. if value does not match with pi serial value then game over and give score user's correct value. 

you can check http://www.cow-pi.com/ site.

one more thing please give me some time to solve this problem I will pay you if you want. I am asking for help but you are spend a lot of time that's why it my offer.

Comment: if there is a lot of code to discuss we can discuss it here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226477/code-debugging

Comment: it seems I need 20 reputation and I don't have.
hamidur.me09@gmail.com is my gmail and skype also.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood from question:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const PiGame = () => {
  const [pracInput, setPracInput] = useState("1415");
  const pi = "141592653589793238462643";
  useEffect(() => {
    let subscribed = true;
    const runLoop2 = async () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < pracInput.length; i++) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        if (subscribed) {
         if (pracInput[i] === pi[i]) {
            console.log(i)
            console.log(true);
          } else {
            console.log(false);
          }
        }
  }
};
    runLoop2();

   return () => subscribed = false; // to avoid memory leak on unmount of component


  }, []);. // Passing empty array will make it execute only once, at component mount

  const handleChange = (e) => {
const val = e.target.value;

if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(val)) {
  setPracInput(val);
}
 };


  return (
<div>
  <div>
    <input
      type="text"
      style={{
        width: "80%",
      }}
      value={pracInput}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />

    <div>{pracInput}</div>
  </div>
</div>


);
};

export default PiGame;
```

As you are doing asynchronous task in useEffect you must use some logic/trick to avoid memory leak.

Comment: User will input continuously but the for loop will check without restarting. 

please see cow-pi.com site. please click "Go" or press g from right side and input 1592. you will see it is checking with green bg of text.

Comment: for now I have default value 1415 and for loop start automatically after 1sec. I will input 92653 but the for loop would not restart and complete upto 121592653

Comment: I update my code and description. please take a look and help me if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const PiGame = () => {
  const [pracInput, setPracInput] = useState("1415");
  const pi = "141592653589793238462643";
  const counter = useRef(4); // store the counter
  useEffect(() => {
    const runLoop2 = async () => {
      for (let i = counter.current; i < pracInput.length; i++) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        if (pracInput[i] === pi[i]) {
          console.log(i)
          console.log(true);
        } else {
          console.log(false);
        }
      }
      counter.current = counter.current + pracInput.length;
    };
    runLoop2();
  }, [pracInput]);
  // the rest same as before
```

Comment: User will input continuously but the for loop will check without restarting. please see cow-pi.com site. please click "Go" or press g from right side and input 1592. you will see it is checking with green bg of text.

for now I have default value 1415 and for loop start automatically after 1sec. I will input 92653 but the for loop would not restart and complete upto 121592653

Comment: I changed to useRef(4) to account for the fact there are already 4 digits entered

Comment: I update my code and description. please take a look and help me if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because you added "pracInput" in the array. "UseEffect" excutes everytime you call it and therefore will always call the looping function to start over. To stop this, you could either remove the "pracInput" from the dependency array and get the value in another way or you could use the "UseState" hook to set a certain value when the loop starts and then base a condition on your loop function call.
Something like this

```
const [cond, setCond] = useState(false);
```

Set its value to be true when the loop starts then add a condition like this

```
if(cond == false)
     runLoop2();
```

Comment: User will input continuously but the for loop will check without restarting. please see cow-pi.com site. please click "Go" or press g from right side and input 1592. you will see it is checking with green bg of text. for now I have default value 1415 and for loop start automatically after 1sec. I will input 92653 but the for loop would not restart and complete upto 121592653

Comment: I update my code and description. please take a look and help me if possible.

Comment: @HamidurRahman I read it again and I don't understand what you want to do. If you want the value of loop to start from somewhere, you could just set the value to a state variable and make it the starting point while adding to it in every loop. If that works with you then good. If not, you need to make it clear what you want to do.

Comment: you can run my update code and please wait 4s.
you will get counting: 4, progress width: 48
now input 9, means value would be 14159
I want counting: 5 and progress width: 60
add another digit 2 means value would be 141592
I want counting: 6 and progress width: 72

Comment: @HamidurRahman I don't understand what you want to do. From what I understand, you can just use a "useState" and set the counter variable to be equal to it.